# Merging 2 SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server, resultset

I've got 2 queries I'd like to merge into 1 result set without using union.

Query 1

```
select  datepart(yy,dateclosed)as 'Year',
    datepart(mm,dateclosed) as 'Month',
    count(*)as 'Total' 
from bug 
where projectid = 44 
and ifclosed = 1
and isnull(createdbyperson,1) <> '-1111111110'
and datepart(yy,dateclosed) > '2000'
group by datepart(yy,dateclosed), datepart(mm,dateclosed)
order by 1,2
```

Query 2

```
select  datepart(yy,dateclosed)as 'Year',
    datepart(mm,dateclosed) as 'Month',
    count(*)as 'SameDay' 
from bug 
where   projectid = 44 
        and ifclosed = 1
        and isnull(createdbyperson,1) <> '-1111111110'
        and datepart(yy,dateclosed) > '2000' 
        and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateclosed, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), datecreated, 101) 
group by datepart(yy,dateclosed),datepart(mm,dateclosed)
order by 1,2
```

Id like it to return the values as Year,Month,SameDay,Total.  How do I achieve this? Union doesn't do what I want it to do.  Do I have to do a join and a table alias?  Subquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like for a union and what error is given?

Comment: I don't want to use union because it merges that data into a 3 column table and makes the records hard to determine the values.

Comment: Union is not the right statement for this query. You need to treat your two queries as subqueries which are joined together.  Or, I bet the desired query could be written as one query since the two you have posted are very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK...what about this one:

```
select a.Year, a.Month, b.SameDay, a.Total
from
(
select  datepart(yy,dateclosed)as 'Year',
    datepart(mm,dateclosed) as 'Month',
    count(*)as 'Total' 
from bug 
where projectid = 44 
and ifclosed = 1
and isnull(createdbyperson,1) <> '-1111111110'
and datepart(yy,dateclosed) > '2000'
group by datepart(yy,dateclosed), datepart(mm,dateclosed)
) a
inner join
(
select  datepart(yy,dateclosed)as 'Year',
    datepart(mm,dateclosed) as 'Month',
    count(*)as 'SameDay' 
from bug 
where   projectid = 44 
        and ifclosed = 1
        and isnull(createdbyperson,1) <> '-1111111110'
        and datepart(yy,dateclosed) > '2000' 
        and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateclosed, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), datecreated, 101) 
group by datepart(yy,dateclosed),datepart(mm,dateclosed)
) b
on a.Year = b.Year AND a.Month = b.Month
order by 1,2
```

Comment: The union works but doesn't return the data in the format I'd like, Year, Month, SameDay, Total. It returns as 
Year1,month1,sameday 
Year1,Month1,Total 
Year2,month2,sameday 
Year2,Month2,Total etc

Comment: Yes! Perfect, that does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy,dateclosed) AS 'Year',
    DATEPART(mm,dateclosed) AS 'Month',
    SUM(IF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateclosed, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), datecreated, 101), 1, 0)) AS SameDay,
    COUNT(*) AS 'Total' 
FROM bug 
WHERE projectid = 44 
    AND ifclosed = 1
    AND ISNULL(createdbyperson,1) <> '-1111111110'
    AND DATEPART(yy,dateclosed) > '2000'
GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,dateclosed), DATEPART(mm,dateclosed)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Returns incorrect syntax errors:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: What SQL server? That was code for MySQL. For MS SQL Server, use CASE: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/iif_tsql_p1.aspx

Comment: SQL Server 2005, didn't explicitly say that, instead just tagged sql server

Answer (score 0):

Without using a union you could create a temporary table, write the results of the two queries into it and then query the temporary table.

I suspect that you shouldn't be doing this, but rather working out why the union isn't working for you.

What have you tried?

What happened?

Comment: Union works, but it doesn't return the data in the manner in which I am trying to achieve, a 4 column layout.  Union merges it all into a 3 column list.

Comment: Union is not the right syntax for this query - he is trying to join together 2 subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that you want to do this? Are you aware that you can just have the query return multiple result sets:

```
SELECT -- query 1

SELECT -- query 2
```

Your client can then read the 2 result sets independently - it depends on the langauge you use but in C# using SqlDataReader you use `NextResult`

```
SqlDataReader reader = GetReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Process result of query 1
}
reader.NextResult();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Process result of query 2
}
```

Comment: To create a report to distribute to people.  Scoregraphic's query above achieves what I was looking to accomplish, a 4 column layout from 2 3 column queries.